# how to change features connected to vim at compilation?

Tags: vim

I'm working in vim and having a problem.  On my primary macbook pro, I have vim running in iterm via macvim terminal mode.  Normally, I can have multiple tabs open ie, tab1 is rails app a and tab 2 is rails app b, and I can yank y lines from tab1 and paste p them into tab2. On my macbook air, I can't seem to paste between tabs.  I'm sharing the bundle dire and bash_profile between the two computers via dropbox so the configuration should be good.  The one problem I think I'm noticing is that when I run `vim --version` on the correctly functioning machine, I get

```
  VIM - Vi Improved 7.3 (date)  
  MacOs X (unix) version   
Included patches: 1-754  
compiled by usr@usr-macbook-pro.local  
Huge version with MacVim GUI
```

and when I run `vim --version` on my mac book air, the non correctly functioning machine I get
V

```
IM - Vi IMproved 7.3 (2010 Aug 15, compiled Oct 23 2012 13:50:52)  
Compiled by root@apple.com  
Normal version without GUI.  Features included (+) or not (-):
```

and I notice that in the correctly functioning machine the features list has +clipboard and in the non functioning machine the feature list has -clipboard.  how do I change this to reflect the proper configuration on the macbook air?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try running

```
brew install macvim --override-system-vim
```

followed by

```
brew link macvim
```

However, it looks like the version of vim you are using on your macbook air is not the macvim version you are looking for. It's the standard version of vim. What is the output of `which -a vim`? You may have to add macvim to your path on your macbook air before the builtin vim. What does `echo $PATH` output?

Answer (score 0):

i just uninstalled macvim via homebrew and reinstalled it making careful to connect the symlink to the application folder correctly.  everything now works.

Comment: Symlinks are ugly. Why don't you simply download MacVim?